# Please help me understand protocol buffers

Tags: java, python, protocol-buffers

I'm missing something with protobuffers. Here is some questions that I have that I'm having difficulties answering.

- Is a .proto file enough to have get all the data out of? In the address book example that is on the site they seem to write the data out to a file and consume it out of a file (separate than the .proto file itself). I understand that the proto serializes the object structure and I know that it can serialize a message however I'm having a hard time finding where to put the data and retrieve within one contained .proto file itself.
- If question above is answered as I think it would my assumption is that one team can create the proto file and serialize the data with with java and another team can simply take the file and use python to deserialze it is that correct assumption?

Answer (score 3):

> Is a .proto file enough to have get all the data out of?

The `proto` file is used to define the structure of the message. Each field is given a tag number. As long as you have the right `proto` file, the data can be de-serialized correctly. Yes the `proto` file will suffice.

> one team can create the proto file and serialize the data with with
>   java and another team can simply take the file and use python to
>   deserialze it is that correct assumption?

One team can create the structure needed to define the data being sent / received and others can use that definition to communicate. As long as both teams use the same `.proto` file and the tag numbers are assigned correctly, you should have no trouble doing what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way

Client side java code
- **proto encoder**
- - bytes
======= network =======
- - bytes
- **proto decoder**
Server side java code

Instead of the network, the bytes may be written to a file by one side and read from it by the other. Whichever.

In order for **proto encoder** and **proto decoder** to do their job, they need to understand the format of the bytes coming in. `proto` file describes that format.

It's somewhat analogous to sending an image over the network: both sides need to know it's a `png` file. If one sends `png` and the other tries to decode `jpg`, things won't work. The same way as `jpg` vs `png` describe the image format, `proto` files describe the data format.